# Free app unavailable in android market (checked for device fulfilling all requirements)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I published an application on android market (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mrgorsky.remoteprank).

Problem: detail page shows, that it's incompatible with my phone and thus I can't install it (other phone has the same problem). Phone fulfills all requirements (Android version, required hardware etc.), application works fine when installed manually.

Any ideas? Thanks.

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mrgorsky.remoteprank"
  android:versionCode="5"
  android:versionName="1.2.2">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
  android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="RemotePrank"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name="ControllerActivity"
      android:label="Choose prank and phone number"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
<activity android:name="HelpActivity"
      android:label="Help"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
<service android:name="SmsReceiverService">
</service>
<activity android:name="BustedActivity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

---

Update:
Application started to behave ok (appears in search results and compatibility issues are gone) without any action.

Answer (score 1):

It works for both my Nexus S and HTC Magic in Spain.

Is your Android 2.1 or newer?

Comment: Well, it just started working (have no idea what was wrong..). Thank you very much for your time and effort.